# Can Insert objects created from the same Storage object be executed concurrently?

Tags: java, google-api-java-client, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client

I'm using Google's Java API to work with Google Cloud Storage (GCS).

I have multiple worker threads that insert objects into GCS.  Currently they share a common [`Storage`](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/apis/storage/v1beta1/index.html) instance, and use this to create [`Storage.Object.Insert`](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg-history/92901c2b5aea5d9747060b3d240d64f38ea0b60c/apis/storage/v1beta1/com/google/api/services/storage/Storage.Objects.Insert.html) instances:

```
synchronized(LOCK)
{
    insertObject = mStorage.objects().insert(mBucketName, objectMetadata, mediaContent);
}
```

They later call `execute()` on the `Insert` instance, uploading a file to GCS.

```
insertObject.execute();
```

My question is can I run the `execute()` call concurrently in different threads?  The `Insert` object is unique to that thread, but the `Storage` object it was created with is shared between threads, so I'm worried this may cause problems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would expect this to work just fine but I will see if I can find a more authoritative answer from someone who knows more about the java api client.

Comment: [This issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=144) leads me to believe that it's thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, so it looks like it's pretty safe to assume it is thread safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! :)

That is, assuming the HttpTransport instance you are using is thread-safe, then having a shared Storage instance should be thread safe.  What is not safe is to share the request class itself or its response across threads without additional locking that you provide. But as long as each thread is using its own request class, it is safe and in fact recommended to share the Storage and instance across threads.

Note: I am an owner of the google-api-java-client project